# Multiple reference readers and one reference writer in Rust

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm currently working on a small Rust game to start with the language and have basically the following code (I only wrote a minimal example here):

```rust
struct Player<'a> {
    pub ship: &'a Ship<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Player<'a> {
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        // Does some computing with self.ship.x/self.ship.y
    }
}

struct Ship<'a> {
    pub players: Vec<Player<'a>>,
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

impl<'a> Ship<'a> {
    pub fn add_player(&mut self, player: Player<'a>) {
        self.players.push(player);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ship = Ship {
        players: vec![],
        x: 0.0,
        y: 0.0,
    };

    // At some point create a player for the ship
    let player = Player { ship: &ship };
    ship.add_player(player); // <- Forbidden
}
```

The most important thing here is that all `Player`s have access to the ship they belong to with an immutable reference, so that they easily have access to the position (x/y) of their ship (which changes over time, as the game runs). However, this code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `ship` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:32:5
   |
31 |     let player = Player { ship: &ship };
   |                                 ----- immutable borrow occurs here
32 |     ship.add_player(player);
   |     ^^^^^----------^^^^^^^^
   |     |    |
   |     |    immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand that `player` is borrowing `ship` as immutable and that I'm still trying to modify `ship` after the borrow occurs, but I can't find what is the right smart pointer or wrapper I should use for this kind of case? Would you use a `RwLock`, or a `RefCell`, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea in that you would probably need to use RefCell, or RwLock or maybe even Rc. However, these concepts are more advanced and I do not recommend trying to use them when you're just starting to learn the language. Instead, I would remove the Ship reference from the Player struct and just have the Ship contain references to Players.

If you haven't already, I highly recommend the [official rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), its a great introduction to the language with great examples!

Comment: Thanks, will take a look! Still curious about this issue... Are you able to confirm that something like Vec<RefCell<Player<'a>>> would be the solution to my problem and there's no way to make it work just by using simple references?

Comment: Yes, I believe Vec<RefCell<Player<'a>>> that would work. Since player is keeping a borrowed reference of the ship, there's no way to mutate the ship while the player has it, thus, I do not believe there is any way to make it work using simple references.